# Query time too long using replace on select query

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to use a `REPLACE` function in a select subquery but it is taking too long. If I don't use `REPLACE` in the subquery, it is a lot faster. I need to use `REPLACE` to change the order_id from '.001' to '.000' to make the first select

example that loads fast

```
select product 
from orders 
where order_id in (select order_id 
                   from orders 
                   where customer_id = 10)
```

what I am trying but it take ages to load

```
select product 
from orders 
where order_id in (select REPLACE(order_id,'.001','.000') as order_id_new 
                   from orders  
                   where customer_id = 10)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: With REPLACE you are making query non-SARGable

Comment: OK, do you recommend something else ?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: Do both queries return the same number of rows?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: the second query could still use an index on `orders.order_id` if applicable.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, but still index scan will be slower than corresponding index seek

Comment: I have no idea what the difference between an "index scan" and "index seek" is supposed to be, but the comparison value used e.g. for the `order_id =` part of the IN always compares the `order_id` with a constant value and that won't influence the efficiency of the index usage on `order_id`

Comment: what data type `order_id` is ? is it floating point (single, double) or text (varchar, char, text blob) ???

Comment: `I have no idea what the difference between an "index scan" and "index seek" is supposed to be` - added you to links to read

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is some information about your situation missed in your question yet.

1. What data type `order_id` is ? is it floating point (single, double) or text (`varchar`, `char`, text `blob`) ???
2. What indices do you have over those two tables ?
3. What `query plans` do both your queries spawn ?

Generally `IN` works poorly on large lists in Interbase/Firebird and usually it is better to be replaced with joining tables. Sometimes even using `Global Temporary Tables` for keeping the list of IDs.

Try this:

```
With O2 as (
   select DISTINCT REPLACE(order_id,'.001','.000') as order_id 
     from orders
     where customer_id = 10
)
Select O1.product 
  from orders O1
  join O2 on O1.order_id = O2.order_id
```

> I have no idea what the difference between an "index scan" and "index seek" is supposed to be

there here are two links to read

- https://ib-aid.com/en/articles/how-to-track-slow-select-statement-in-the-production-firebird-database/
- http://www.ibase.ru/dataaccesspaths/

The latter is in Russian, and written in 2006 by Firebird core developer. I believe it was translated into English but did not find it. Read it via http://Translate.ru

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select product 
from orders 
where REPLACE(order_id,'.000','.001') in (select order_id as order_id_new 
                                          from orders  
                                          where customer_id = 10)
```

note that REPLACE function's 2nd and 3rd parameters are swapped.